# c# while loop doesn't end

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop

Problem: Loop is designed to add up numbers the user enters until the user enters 999. Once the user ***enters*** 999, the result of all numbers the user entered, except 999, are displayed on the screen. Right now, even when you enter 999, it says **intResult** is an unused unassigned local variable.  Code is below:

```
//Application Name: Sum
//Date:             January 27th, 2017
//Purpose:          Allows user to enter a number of integer values
//                  until they reach 999 and display the values 
//                  entered.


    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Declare Variables
        int intEnterVariable;
        string strEnterVariable;
        int intResult;
        int intLimit = 999;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter in a number");
        Console.WriteLine("When done, enter 999");
        strEnterVariable = Console.ReadLine();
        intEnterVariable = Convert.ToInt32(strEnterVariable);

        //Accept user input
        while (intEnterVariable != intLimit)
        {
            //Read user input
            Console.WriteLine("Enter another number");
            strEnterVariable = Console.ReadLine();
            intEnterVariable = Convert.ToInt32(strEnterVariable);
            intResult += intEnterVariable;
        }

            Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", intResult.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit");
            Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Do you know how to use a debugger?

Comment: Why are you doing this?  `intEnterVariable += intEnterVariable;`  If the user enters 999, then you're making it 1998.  Since 1998 != 999, the loop continues.  That loop *can't* end, because to do so the user would have to enter a value which when added to itself equals 999.  999 is an odd number, so it's impossible.

Comment: I have tried debugging and can't figure it out. How do you add up the numbers the user enters and then display them?

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that when you enter the first number it gets added to intEnterVariable and then when you enter second number your While match limit becomes intEnterVaribale + your previous entry, which is always greater than 999, so it never goes past the While, here's your solution :

```
{

        //Declare Variables
        int intEnterVariable=0;
        string strEnterVariable;
        int intResult;
        int intLimit = 999;

        //int Total Variable
        int intTotal=0;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter in a number");
        Console.WriteLine("When done, enter 999");
        strEnterVariable = Console.ReadLine();
        intEnterVariable = Convert.ToInt32(strEnterVariable);
        intTotal = intEnterVariable;
        //Accept user input

        while (intEnterVariable != intLimit)
        {
            //Read user input
            Console.WriteLine("Enter another number");
            strEnterVariable = Console.ReadLine();
            intEnterVariable = Convert.ToInt32(strEnterVariable);
            intTotal = intTotal + intEnterVariable;
        }
        intTotal = intTotal - 999;
        intResult = intTotal;
        Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", intResult.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Happy Coding ! :)

Comment: The code is intended to add that numbers the user enters and then once the user actually enters the number 999, it displays the results of all numbers entered by the user except 999. Hope that helps!

Comment: Got the solution, hope this helps, I've updated the code. Give it a try ! and do mark as answer if it works for you :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use a separate variable for the current number you're taking in, and your total count. Right now it's checking if intEnterVariable equals 999. If I enter 500 the first time, and 500 the second time, intEnterVariable = 1000. It will never equal 999, so the loop with go forever.

Answer (score 1):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //Declare Variables
    int intEnterVariable;
    string strEnterVariable;

    // 
    // You need to give initial value here
    //
    int intResult = 0;
    int intLimit = 999;
```

Answer (score 0):

> until the user enters 999

What happens when the user enters 999?...

```
intEnterVariable = Convert.ToInt32(strEnterVariable);
```

The variable `intEnterVariable` now equals 999.  Then...

```
intEnterVariable += intEnterVariable;
```

The variable `intEnterVariable` now equals 1998.  Then...

```
while (intEnterVariable != intLimit)
```

1998 does not equal 999, so the loop continues.

---

Perhaps you meant to do this?:

```
intResult += intEnterVariable;
```

Though even still, immediately after the loop you do this:

```
intResult = intEnterVariable;
```

So that will clobber any value you stored there before.  It's possible that you may have quite a few logical errors here, and you should really take this as an opportunity to familiarize yourself with the use of a debugger so you can step through the code and observe the logic and variable values to see what your code is doing and where the behavior changes from what you expect.

But at the very least, the above is why the loop is an infinite loop.  Because `intEnterVariable += intEnterVariable;` will never (can never, being an integer) equal 999.

Comment: I understand all of the answers that have been provided and I apologize for not understanding earlier. I changed it so the result says intResult += intEnterVariable. Now the only problem is the answer is off

Comment: @ChrisShaw: "off" how?  Describe the problem.  This also continues to be an opportune time for you to start using a debugger, which is in every way the most valuable and useful skill of any programmer.

Comment: I figured it out! I have used a debugger before and I used it but it was really a simple fix, will post as answer.

Answer (score 0):

using System;

namespace _01CH4SumChrisShaw
{
    public class Sum
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Declare Variables
            int intEnterInteger;
            string strEnterInteger;
            int intResult = 0;
            int intLimit = 999;

```
        Console.WriteLine("Enter multiple numbers. Calculate results by entering 999");
        strEnterInteger = Console.ReadLine();
        intEnterInteger = Convert.ToInt32(strEnterInteger);
        intResult += intEnterInteger;

        //Accept user input
        while (intEnterInteger != intLimit)
        {
            //Read user input
            Console.WriteLine("Enter another number");
            strEnterInteger = Console.ReadLine();
            intEnterInteger = Convert.ToInt32(strEnterInteger);
            intResult += intEnterInteger;
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", intResult - intLimit);
            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit");
            Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}